# How to read multi-value library with for loop in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Assume that CSV file has this content:

```
Main1,Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4
Main2,NameA,NameB
Main3,Name11,Name12,Name13
```

When I read it as library result is following:

```
{'Main1': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4'],
 'Main2': ['NameA', 'NameB'],
 'Main3': ['Name11', 'Name12', 'Name13']}
```

When I turn to particular item/value like `a['Main3'][2]` I'll get answer `'Name13'`.
But the values ('Name's') are unknown number and I would like to read them all individually in e.g. for loop. If I read like this:

```
for rows in a:
    print(rows)
```

I will get answer:

```
Main1
Main2
Main3
```

But I would like to modify code something like:

```
for rows in a:
    print(rows)
    for values in rows:
        print(values)
```

But result is erroneous. I expect to see something like this:

```
'Main1' 
    'Name1'
    'Name2'
    'Name3'
    'Name4'
'Main2'
    'NameA'
    'NameB'
'Main3'
    'Name11'
    'Name12'
    'Name13'
```

And I cannot figure out how to modify my code. Would you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: How are you *reading* that file? That part of your code is missing but it seems important.

Comment: `import csv
def read_names(filename):
    t_names = {}
    for row in csv.reader(open(filename)):
        number = row[0]
        name = row[1:]
        t_names[number] = (name)
    return t_names`

Comment: Yeah ... additional code goes in your post, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do like this.

```
for rows in a:
    print(rows)
    for values in a[rows]:
        print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see `a` is a dictionary. so you want each key and the values,
So, Try this:

```
for k,v in a.items():
    print(k, *v, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
for rows in a:
    print(rows)
    for values in a[rows]:
        print('   ',values)
```